# How to zip files one by one in a directory in linux

Tags: linux

I have a directory where there are files -:
abc_002.txt
abc_003.txt
abc_004.txt
abc_005.txt
xyz_001.txt
for_ex.sh
abc_001.txt

I want to gzip only files starting with names abc, like abc*.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
for file in abc*.txt
do
    gzip $file
done
```